# TypeError: must be str or None, not Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Using an OOP approach to developing a tkinter program for the first time based on the sentdex tkinter series. I honestly have no idea what the error here means.

The error directs me to:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ash\Dropbox\Programming\Python\WorldManager PY\WorldManager.py", line 59, in __init__
tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1867, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
TypeError: must be str or None, not Frame
```

The code I've used is [here](http://pastebin.com/kCGGrpkr)

EDIT: While the code says the line is 59, the error is on line 46. I took out a few comments from above the code when I pastebinned it.

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself, if necessary composing a [mcve] first to make it short enough.

Comment: That error didn't come from the code you linked to. Line 59 does not call `tk.Tk.__init__(...)`

Comment: Add `print(args, kwargs)` before the `Tk.__init__` call so you can see what is actually being passed, in particular, how is a Frame being passed in.

Comment: @BryanOakley what do you mean?

Comment: The error message says the error is on line 59, but line 59 in your code can't possibly produce that error because line 59 is a comment.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy (<tkinter.Frame object .48357680>, <__main__.Worldmanager object .>) {} This is what's printed

Comment: @BryanOakley check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class frmWelcome(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #initialise tkinter
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

You are inheriting from `tk.Frame` yet you are calling `tk.Tk.__init__` You need to be calling `tk.Frame.__init__`

Comment: after making the change there in the code, i get a different error. tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-screen"