# Scale ttk.Frame created from the class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to create Python 3.7+ Tkinter app with another frame which can be brought up by clicking a button:

[Sentdex example](https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/?completed=/passing-functions-parameters-tkinter-using-lambda/)

[Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

I create a class with Tkinter (ThemedTk) and want to create few classes with ttk.Frame. Buttons will switch between the Frames. My issue right now - I can't make the frame to resize and stick 'nesw' to the main root Class. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with ttk.Frame but I can't understand the issue.
I added

```
self.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
```

but it doesn't seem to help...
The entire code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

class MainApp(ThemedTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ThemedTk.__init__(self)
        self.set_theme('equilux', themebg=True)
        self.title('Test App')
        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.DESKTOP_WIDTH = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.DESKTOP_HEIGHT = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.WIDTH = int(self.DESKTOP_WIDTH / 4)
        self.HEIGHT = int(self.DESKTOP_HEIGHT / 2.5)
        self.geometry(f'{self.WIDTH}x{self.HEIGHT}+{int(self.DESKTOP_WIDTH / 3)}+{int(self.DESKTOP_HEIGHT / 4)}')
        self.minsize(width=self.WIDTH, height=self.HEIGHT)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainLogin)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.grid(row=0, column=0)


class MainLogin(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master, padding=(5, 5, 5, 5), borderwidth=10, relief='ridge', sticky='nesw')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.master = master
        self.userid = tk.StringVar()
        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        self.remember = tk.StringVar()

        self.frame_login = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(10, 10, 10, 10), borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')

        self.label_welcome = ttk.Label(self.frame_login, text='Open App')
        self.label_user = ttk.Label(self.frame_login, text='User ID:')
        self.entry_user = ttk.Entry(self.frame_login, textvariable=self.userid)
        self.label_password = ttk.Label(self.frame_login, text='Password:')
        self.entry_password = ttk.Entry(self.frame_login, textvariable=self.password, show='*')
        self.check_remember = ttk.Checkbutton(self.frame_login, text='Remember me', variable=self.remember, onvalue='yes', offvalue='no')
        self.button_login = ttk.Button(self.frame_login, text='Login', command=lambda: MainLogin.login(self.userid, self.password))
        self.button_register = ttk.Button(self.frame_login, text='Register', command=self.register)

        self.grid_widgets()
        self.resize_widgets()

    def grid_widgets(self):
        self.frame_login.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
        self.label_welcome.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=30, sticky='n')
        self.label_user.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='e')
        self.entry_user.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.label_password.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='e')
        self.entry_password.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='w')
        self.check_remember.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, sticky='n')
        self.button_login.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=30, sticky='e')
        self.button_register.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=30, sticky='w')

    def resize_widgets(self):
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.frame_login.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.frame_login.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

    @staticmethod
    def login(userif, password):
        print('Login button pressed')

    def register(self):
        print('Register button pressed')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainApp()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _" i'm getting errors (wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row')"_ - Nowhere in your code do you call `wm_grid`. Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: I updated the code with error. I'm getting different errors depending how and where I plug ThemedTk. As is right now the error is: "TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not Frame". If I replace tk.Tk.__init__ to ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) (as suggester here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532433/typeerror-must-be-str-or-none-not-frame) I get "wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error. Code in the comment section is impossible to read.

Comment: I am sorry... I updated my post.

Comment: Your code runs without error for me.

Comment: That is correct. But if you maximize the window to fullscreen the frame and the contents of the frame won't scale/stick='nsew' even though I thought it should...

Comment: That has nothing to do with the theming. You simply haven't set the code up to expand.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to do rowconfigure and columnconfigure for that frame created from class, so that it scales...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only ever have a single frame in the root window at any one time, the simplest solution is to use `pack` instead of `grid`, since you don't have to worry about configuring rows and columns.

```
def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
    """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
    new_frame = frame_class(self)
    if self._frame is not None:
        self._frame.destroy()
    self._frame = new_frame
    self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

With that small change, the `MainLogin` frame will fill the window.

If you prefer using `grid`, you can replace the call to `pack` in the above code with this:

```
self._frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me!